# Set a style for the specific Attribute

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

*.html*

```
<ion-icon name="add" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-add" 
       aria-label="add" ng-reflect-name="add"></ion-icon>
```

*.scss*

```
ion-icon{
  padding:0;//I have done so far.But how can I get the `name` attribute here?
}
```

I need to give style to the attribute `name ="add"` inside the `ion-icon` element.Can you help me for this?

Comment: ion-icon[name="add"] , try this, i hope that works

Comment: @Mark `padding:0` as shown above my post

Comment: `ion-icon[name="add]` will help you with that.

Comment: ```ion-icon{
&[name="add"]
padding:0;
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, try this code for calling the `icon` class with an attribute `name` and equals to `add` value.

*CSS*

```
 .icon[name="add"]{
     padding:0;
  }
```

Comment: because there is no class `ion-icon` on your html please add it or you can call another class you have there

Comment: try `icon` class like this `.icon[name="add"]{ }`

Comment: I cannot do that hence those are inner classes where framework created.

Comment: I see this is the code `ion-icon[name="add"]{ }` don't add dot before the ion-icon

Comment: because it is a tag with an attribute name

Answer (score 0):

You have created an ion-icon html element that doesn't exist. If you add that to the class declaration instead then you can style that class, no attribute selector is needed:

```css
.ion-icon{
  padding:0;
  color: red;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<i class="ion-icon icon icon-md ion-md-add" name="add" role="img" aria-label="add" ng-reflect-name="add">icon here</i>
```

Comment: I cannot do that hence those are inner classes where framework created.

Comment: What is creating that non-semantic element? Whatever is doing it should probably not be used as it won't validate, and some browsers won't even render it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
[name="add"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ion-icon name="add" role="img" class="icon icon-md ion-md-add" aria-label="add" ng-reflect-name="add">Hello World</ion-icon>
```